# I can't get data from database with 'for'

Tags: flutter

I use flutter and firebase but ı cant get multiple data from database help me

```dart
hotelekle(
                         
 "${hotel5yildiz[0]["foto"]}",                        
 "${hotel5yildiz[0]["adi"]}",                         
 "${hotel5yildiz[0]["puan"]}"),
```

```dart
Padding hotelekle(String resimadres, String hotelad, String puan) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      right: 40,
      left: 40,
      bottom: 15,
    ),
    child: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 3,
                    blurRadius: 4,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3),
                  ),
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                child: Image.network(
                  "$resimadres",
                  width: 300,
                  height: 150,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35, left: 40, bottom: 7),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "$hotelad",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff2C1E40),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35, left: 45),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  size: 16,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  "$puan",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.bed,
                  color: Color(0xff4A9CC9),
                  size: 22,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                  "Hotel",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: what's the error you got ?

Comment: I don't get error.I don't know exactly where and how to use 'for'

Comment: please share some code, so it's easy for us to understand the issue.

Comment: There is no `for` anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

By multiple data, I'm assuming you want to get a list of items from firebase. In that case, you can use StreamBuilder. I am sharing with you a snippet of code and you can adjust based on your needs.
On the widget tree, where you want to render the list of data, add in a StreamBuilder

```
Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<dynamic?>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').snapshots();,
              builder:(context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                } else if(snapshot.hasData){

                  final List sd = [];
                  snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                    Map m = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    sd.add(m);
                  }).toList();


                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: sd.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return Item(name: sd[index]['attribute1'], text: sd[index]['attribute2'],);
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                }
              },
            )
          )
```

If you have any further queries, let me know and I'll make sure to get back to you.

Comment: sorry i wrote my problem wrong my problem is not to print the data one by one but to print all of them with a loop

Comment: What do you mean by all of them in a loop? Is it a list of data or just a document you want to print? The same solution still applies if it's a list of data. You just have to replace map with a for loop.

Comment: Printing the information I pulled from the firebase sequentially with the help of a loop

Comment: So, it's not a list of data? If it's not a list of data, then I'm not sure why you would need a for loop.